# Copy folder into another folder

Tags: windows, perl, cmd

I want to copy one directory into another, running the command with Perl interpreter (not using Perl to perform the copy)

I tried:

```
my $do = "xcopy /E \"D:\/folder1\" \"D:\/folder2\"";
system($do);
```

But it copies only the files inside `folder1` to the folder `folder2`.
How can I make it to copy the whole `folder2` to `folder1`.

The expected structure would be :

```
folder2
  | folder1
  |   |   other_files
```

I **DON'T want to do this in Perl**

Comment: is it really related to `perl` ?

Comment: ... or `bash` ? if you want to copy a directory in `bash`, use `cp`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I was afraid that someone would complain about  `this is not pure cmd language, why no perl tagged?`

Comment: What tag would be proper?

Comment: @redneb Not a duplicate since I don't want to implement it using perl libraries.

Comment: I have edited the post, maybe it's clearer now.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, now it's clearer. Thank you again!

Comment: This is not a batch file.  Please remove that tag.

Comment: @Squashman can you tell me which would be the proper tag?

Comment: @JohnDoe, what language is that? it looks like a `cmd`/batch command line embedded in something else; please state what it is (by adding the applicable tag(s) only)!

Comment: @aschipfl I tagged it first as `batch-file`,`Bash` and `Perl`, then someone asked: "`Is this really related to Perl?`" I am confused as well and asked for tag suggestions, yet no one gave a proper one. The code is written in `Perl` and it includes a `cmd` command which is executed with the command `system($do)`.

Comment: The tags should *reflect what you actually want*, not what you somehow mention in your question. So if I got it right, you want a `cmd` command line to be called by Perl code, is that correct? if so, I suggest to add a related statement to your question and to apply the tags [tag:cmd] and [tag:pearl]. A [tag:batch-file] is a file holding `cmd` commands, but I think you do not want that, so that tag does not apply. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39510929/edit) your question accordingly...

Answer (score 3):

change you line to add `/I` option to `xcopy` and add the target folder1 to the 2nd argument:

```
my $do = 'xcopy /E /I "D:/folder1" "D:/folder2/folder1"';

/I: create dirs if don't exist
```

Comment: I did not try through perl. I created a folder called `1` and I run this: `xcopy /E /I 1 2\1`: it copies all files in `1` in `2/1` and it creates the directories. I'm on windows 7 / 2008 server

Comment: Thank you kindly, I just realized how simple it was..

Comment: no problem. MS-DOS commands have a logic of their own. I never seem to be able to remember the "subtleties" ever.

Comment: To avoid escaping the inner double quotes `\"` you can use single quotes outside: `my $do = 'xcopy /E /I "D:/folder1" "D:/folder2/folder1"';`.

Comment: better like this. I'm no perl expert.